# Wildfly-14 : java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.xml.dtm.ref.DTMManagerDefault cannot be cast to org.apache.xml.dtm.DTMManager

Tags: wildfly-12

I am getting following error while applying xslt in wildfly 14. Sometime it is successfully transform the xml and sometime it gives following error.

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.xml.dtm.ref.DTMManagerDefault cannot be cast to org.apache.xml.dtm.DTMManager

    at org.apache.xml.dtm.DTMManager.newInstance(DTMManager.java:137)

    at org.apache.xpath.XPathContext.<init>(XPathContext.java:102)

    at org.apache.xpath.XPathContext.<init>(XPathContext.java:349)

    at org.apache.xpath.XPathContext.<init>(XPathContext.java:337)

    at org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerImpl.<init>(TransformerImpl.java:397)

    at org.apache.xalan.templates.StylesheetRoot.newTransformer(StylesheetRoot.java:200)
```

I have added following dependency in pom.xml file

```
<dependency>  
    <groupId>xalan</groupId>  
    <artifactId>xalan</artifactId>  
    <version>2.7.1</version>    
</dependency>
```

Comment: It looks like you've got xalan on your class path twice. Try adding `<scope>provided</scope>` to your dependency.

Comment: Hi, I have developed xslt using xalan 2.7.1. If I make xalan dependency as provided then it gives xslt compilation error